# StringPartition vs Partition and StringReplace vs ReplaceAll

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I am trying to make substitution cipher solver based on quadgram statistics.
I am now in doubt about how to store ciphertext - whether in string or in list of characters.
I did a little test to compare how fast is manipulation of strings versus manipulation of list of characters.

```
st = FromCharacterCode[RandomInteger[{65, 90}, 10000000]];
li = Characters[st];
stpa = StringPartition[st, 4, 1]; // Timing
lipa = Partition[li, 4, 1]; // Timing
StringReplace[
   stpa, {"A" -> "Z", "Z" -> "A", "B" -> "Y", "Y" -> "B"}]; // Timing
ReplaceAll[
   lipa, {"A" -> "Z", "Z" -> "A", "B" -> "Y", "Y" -> "B"}]; // Timing
Clear[st, li, stpa, lipa]

(* {3.5625, Null} *)
(* {0.515625, Null} *)
(* {3.53125, Null} *)
(* {16.9531, Null} *)
```

It can be seen that partitioning string is about 7 times slower than partitioning list of characters.
On the other hand it can be seen that swapping characters of partitioned string is about 5 times faster than swapping characters of partitioned list of characters.

**Why are there so significant differences in the speed when in principle results of both procedures are same?**

**What are suggestion to optimize the code?**

I guess in the search for the key of substitution cipher I will use more frequently swapping of characters than partitioning so probably I will use strings and `StringReplace` rather than list of characters and `ReplaceAll`. Or is there a better solutions?

Comment: This `Replace[lipa,Dispatch[{"A"->"Z","Z"->"A","B"->"Y","Y"->"B"}],{2}]` is a bit faster.

Comment: I did not know about `Dispatch`, seems to be a good thing for long replacement rules.

Answer (score 5):

First create all needed data:

```
st = FromCharacterCode[RandomInteger[{65, 90}, 10000000]];
li = Characters[st];
stpa = StringPartition[st, 4, 1]; // Timing
lipa = Partition[li, 4, 1]; // Timing
stpa1 = StringReplace[
    stpa, {"A" -> "Z", "Z" -> "A", "B" -> "Y", 
     "Y" -> "B"}]; // Timing
lipa1 = ReplaceAll[
    lipa, {"A" -> "Z", "Z" -> "A", "B" -> "Y", "Y" -> "B"}]; // Timing
```

Now look at the space used:

```
ByteCount /@ {st, li, stpa, lipa, stpa1, lipa1}

(* {10000072, 400000080, 399999960, 2079999456, 399999960, 2079999456} *)
```

Note that going from st to stpa the space increases 40 times. However going from li to lipa only 5 times. This may explain the first 2 timings.

The timing for the replacements may be explained by noting that the string replacement has to search much less data than the list replacement.

Comment: I think I will rather use Python as there I have more control over speed of all procedures. I am not sure Mathematica is suitable for such a project as substitution cipher solver - that is probably why there is no public code of such solver implemented in Mathematica. At least I have not seen any, but I saw implementations in Python or even in JavaScript available as an open source.